# Find $a,b,c$ such that $(2\cdot 1-1)+(2\cdot 2-1)+(2\cdot 3-1)+...+(2\cdot n-1)=an^2+bn+c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find $a,b,c$ such that $(2\cdot 1-1)+(2\cdot 2-1)+(2\cdot 3-1)+...+(2\cdot n-1)=an^2+bn+c$

Can I get some hints?

Comment: Based on the pattern on the LHS, I think you meant the first term to be $(2*1-1)$ instead of $(2*1-n)$, unless you meant to put it like that. Also, "such as" should be "such that" in the question.

Comment: It is the sum of first n odd numbers that is $n^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS is the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers, which results in $n^2$. So the equation becomes: $$n^2=an^2+bn+c$$in which $\boxed{a=1,b=c=0}$ follows(comparing coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Try to substitute small values for $n$ (say $0,1$ and $2$) and make a system of 3 equations. Result prove with induction.

Hint 2:  $$1+2+3+...+n = {n(n+1)\over 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

for $n=1$,  $a+b+c=1$
for $n=2$,  $4a+2b+c=4$
for $n=3$,  $9a+3b+c=9$
$a=1, b=c=0$